# Error at connecting to REST Twiiter API with python

Tags: python, rest, twitter

I am trying to connect to the Twitter REST API. I downloaded the twitter packages with pi in the command line. In another program I did I could connect to the stream Twitter API. This is my code:

## Import the necessary package to process data in JSON format

```
try:
    import json
    except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

# Import the necessary methods from "twitter" library
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
oauth = OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

twitter = Twitter(auth=OAuth)

twitter.statuses.home_timeline()
```

I am getting this error:

```
line 263, in __call__
headers.update(self.auth.generate_headers())
TypeError: generate_headers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is

`twitter = Twitter(auth=oauth)`

Comment: Thanks Bobby, sorry for not catching it earlier.

Comment: @felipe I will be thrilled if you can upvote and accept XD.

Comment: #Bobby since my reputation score is less than fifteen my vote won't be shown, but it will be recorded :)